# Javascript conduct Math operations using formula entered in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple inputs like a1, a2, a3 etc. What I'd like to do is to enter the formula in another field and conduct the math operation accordingly.

For example: (a1+a3)*a2, and according to the field values the sum is calculated. The values and formulas are dynamic so I have to somehow parse the formula in order to do this operation. Any thoughts how can I proceed?

Comment: Can post an example in a fiddle?

Comment: would you kindly show your sample-code which you try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ydcnzn6/1/)

JS code:

```
function calc() {
    var formula = document.getElementById('formula').value;
    var a1 = document.getElementById('a1').value;
    var a2 = document.getElementById('a2').value;
    var a3 = document.getElementById('a3').value;
    formula = formula.replace('a1', a1).replace('a2', a2).replace('a3', a3);

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "The result is "+eval(formula);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the expression can be computed by javascript, you could replace the variable names with the values from the corresponding input field values. Then you could use the eval javascript function on the variable and the result will be computed. For example `var a = "(a1+a3)*a2"; var b = a.replace("a1", 8).replace("a2", 3).replace("a3", 6); eval(b);` The result will be 42 as expected.